# Facebook JS SDK vs PHP SDK for login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Do most web-apps use Facebook's PHP SDK or Javascript SDK to handle logins?

I'm not clear from their documentation why I would use the more complex PHP SDK? Does it give me more freedom to customize the login experience, etc?

Answer (score 5):

- **Security**: Both are secured. PHP-SDK is more secured.
- **UX**: Js-SDK Login is most appreciated, but gives bad UX when browser's pop-up blocker blocks the login pop-up.
- If **Javascript is disabled** in client's side you'll have to handle that.
- Once user is logged in anyways you'll have process the data in server side unless until you are just displaying the data and not storing them.
- PHP-SDK Login is much easier to implement than Js-SDK, main reason for why I am saying this is "Event Handling and Call-Back Functions". **You should be having decent knowledge about "Event Handling and Call-Back Functions" if you are implementing Js-SDK Login**.
- The control over the login flow is completely with You and Facebook in case
  of PHP-SDK. But in case of Js-SDK users can play with the login flow and you can't stop them.

Now the decision is yours to make...

Comment: What exactly do you mean with your last point? I can’t see what the user could “do” with the client-side login flow that the server-side flow would not allow?

Comment: I mean to say that, after user is authenticated by facebook, the next step that should happen within the platform is visible to them, because its written using Javascript. I didn't mean that We can skip facebook login or something. Sorry if that is misguiding.

Answer (score 0):

Logins are handle by facebook. In the php SDK you do what do you want with a AccessToken. I prefer PHP SDK because your code are on your side and the client only see the output. On the other hand with javascript the "load weight" is on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not clear from their documentation why I would use the more complex PHP SDK? Does it give me more freedom to customize the login experience, etc?

There are some basic differences in what is called the *client-side* login flow and the *server-side* login flow.

For example, the server-side flow already returns a user access token that is valid for 60 days, where as client-side it’s short-lived (2 hours) and has to be extended with another server-side call if it is to be used for longer.